# WP execute shortcode with exeptions via post id in function.php

Tags: php, wordpress, function, shortcode

I have this function below to execute a shortcode on my Wordpress posts.
So far that works great.

Now I would like to exclude some posts via post ID from this function.
For example, I would like to exclude the post with ID 187 and the post with ID 173.

What would be the easiest way to do it? PHP is not really my strong side.
An example would be great.

Thanks
Tony

```
// Add shortcode on posts
add_action( 'genesis_before_content', 'execute_shortcode', 15 );
add_action( 'genesis_entry_footer', 'execute_shortcode', 15 );
function execute_shortcode() {
    if(is_single())
        echo do_shortcode( '[banner1]' );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add to the if the conditional about is single.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_single/

```
If(is_single() && !is_single(your_id)){
```